# Android Studio freezes when right clicking the project explorer

Tags: android-studio, crash, freeze

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 on Kubuntu 15.10 and lately, Android Studio freezes completely whenever I right click into the project explorer. The only thing I can do then is to kill the process.
More oddly, whenever I hover the Help menu with the mouse, the complete OS freezes completely and I have to restart the computer. I am not 100% sure if these two issues are related, but they started at the same time.

Sometimes (about 10% of the time) it works well. I have no idea what influences this pattern, though. This used to happen earlier as well, but much less frequent.

The usage of different color schemes or deactivating plugins seem to have no influence on this behavior. I also did not install any fishy third party software or anything else that could (to my knowledge) have influenced this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be resolved in the latest stable release (2.0).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently run into this as well. Pointing jstack at the hung process suggests that it's [this problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195338).

Switching to the Darcula or GTK+ theme resolved it for me. Weirdly, I can switch back to the Intellij theme afterwards and the problem stays fixed - I just have to switch to GTK+ or Darcula at some point after startup but before triggering a right-click menu.

Edit, 1 day later: In a *deeply unimpressive* plot twist, this solution no longer works for me. I've changed nothing since yesterday, but now attempting to switch themes triggers the lockup ಠ_ಠ

Edit, 1 day, 5 minutes later: After a restart the situation improved slightly - changing the theme now works again, and avoids the freeze-on-rightclick failure. I'm finding it difficult to take this as much of a victory.

Edit: As karpfen notes below, this issue has been resolved in the latest release. Huzzah!

Comment: I read about the GTK+ issue as well. However, I already used Darcula to begin with.

Funnily, I just switched mine to GTK+ for the fun of it and it worked. But that might be just by chance.